# Best way of concatenating or merging files in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, concatenation, grunt-contrib-concat

So i've been searching for the best way of concatenate n (log) files in node.js 
The final file cannot be more than 100MB, if there is more, i should create an other one and so on.

I have some different approaches:

- Use grunt and grunt and https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat
- Use a simple npm like buldify https://github.com/powmedia/buildify
- Do it from scratch with the fs node.js module

I wonder if you could throw me some of your experience here and also this question could be useful for someone in the future.

Cheers!

Comment: cat script1.js script2.js ... scriptn.js > script.js

Answer (score 0):

Both [grunt-contrib-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat) and [buildify](https://github.com/powmedia/buildify) were designed to concatenate JS source files into one bundle, so they are not fit for your task.

I would suggest using something like [logrotate-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logrotate-stream) instead.